# How to prevent Parent class-variable changes to be adopted by Child class

Tags: python, python-2.7, inheritance, class-variables

I was wondering whether it is possible to prevent changes to a Parent class-variable to be adopted by a Child class that inherits from the Parent class.

I would have something like:

```
class Parent(object):
    foo = 'bar'

class Child(Parent):
    pass
```

Overwriting `Parent.foo` will also cause `Child.foo` to change:

```
>>> Parent.foo = 'rab'
>>> print Parent.foo
rab
>>> print Child.foo
rab
```

Is there a way to prevent this or should I not be wanting this?

**Solution**

Reading @quamrana 's answer, I realised this could be prevented using a metaclass:

```
class Meta(type):
    def __new__(cls, new, bases, dct):
        dct['foo'] = 'bar'
        return super(Meta, cls).__new__(cls, new, bases, dct)

class Parent(object):
    __metaclass__ = Meta

class Child(Parent):
    pass
```

```
>>> Parent.foo = 'rab'
>>> print Parent.foo
rab
>>> print Child.foo
bar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour occurs since `foo` is the same variable in both classes.

This is analogous to a global variable in a module and being able to see that two different functions in that module can both see and change that global.

A possible fix is this:

```
class Parent(object):
    foo = 'bar'

class Child(Parent):
    foo = Parent.foo

Parent.foo = 'zoo'
print(Child.foo)
```

Output:

```
bar
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Reading your answer I realised that something like this could also be solved using a metaclass. This prevents the need to add foo=Parent.foo in each class that inherits from Parent